# Clear variables on window close

Tags: dynamic, memory, dialog-window

I'm using

```
DynamicModule[{
var1,
var2
},

CreateDialog[
(*some code here*)
]]
```

In order to be able to deal with memory isolation for multiple copies of a program running at once. Is there an option to use in CreateDialog to run a command upon the closing of that Dialog? When that window gets closed I would like to clear all the variables to free up the memory.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Your code outline is debatable because it'd need `InheritScope -> True` in the dialog to work well. Also, closing the dialog does not destroy the outer `DynamicModule`.
Can you add more details about what do you want to achieve, the flow/logic, what memory you want to free etc? TL;DR: `CreateDialog@DynamicModule[..., Deinitialization-> ...]`

Comment: This will do, thank you very much.